# Is this Microsoft service I found safe to use and/or will it ruin user's privacy?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ipv6, teredo

I was trying to find a IPv6 tunnel after a site needed it, and was about to change the default Teredo config when I realized it was set to Microsoft's servers.

I later ran `netsh int teredo set state client`.

I visited a site to check if I have IPv6 connectivity, and it turned out I suddenly was able to access an IPv6 only website.

I thought it would be interesting to share this with you.

This is the output of `netsh int teredo show state`:

```
Teredo Parameters
---------------------------------------------
Type                    : client
Server Name             : win10.ipv6.microsoft.com.
Client Refresh Interval : 30 seconds
Client Port             : unspecified
State                   : qualified
Client Type             : teredo client
Network                 : unmanaged
NAT                     : restricted (port)
NAT Special Behaviour   : UPNP: Yes, PortPreserving: No
Local Mapping           : 192.168.1.5:62997
External NAT Mapping    : 91.142.61.174:14153
```

I later tried this on other versions of Windows (below Windows 10), and the "Server Name" didn't have win10 at the beginning. I also had IPv6 connectivity without having to signup for any services (with the default config).

I later tried finding Microsoft's documentation on this service, I wasn't able to find much. I searched Microsoft's site more and found [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457011.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

What Microsoft mentioned about the service was:

> The Teredo client in Windows XP SP2, Windows XP SP1 with the Advanced
>   Networking Pack for Windows XP, Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack
>   1, Windows Vista, and Windows Server "Longhorn" automatically attempts
>   to determine the IPv4 addresses of Teredo servers by resolving the
>   name teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com. Alternately, you can use the netsh
>   interface ipv6 set teredo servername= command to configure the IPv4
>   address of a Teredo server.

Also this article was published in January 01, 2003 and updated in January 15, 2007. So this service must have been available for a long time.

The website I used to test IPv6 connectivity was [IPv6-test.com](http://ipv6-test.com/).

What do you think, could this ruin user's privacy and/or is this service safe to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safety and privacy are probably ok if you leave The firewall enabled. The problem with Teredo is that it's so very unreliable in terms of stability and performance.